# Heap corruption during free()

Tags: c, heap-corruption

Here is the Debug information,

```
HEAP[opencv_CoTraining2.exe]: Heap block at 0AD15168 modified at 0AD15594 past requested  size of 424
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in opencv_CoTraining2.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in opencv_CoTraining2.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while opencv_CoTraining2.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

and here is my code:

```
void GetKCent(Mat& mat)
{
    double** tmp=(double**)calloc(mat.rows,sizeof(double*));
    double f[128];
    memset(f,0,sizeof(f));
    double max=0;
    for (int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++) 
    {
        tmp[i]=(double*)calloc(mat.cols,sizeof(double));
        for (int j=0;j<mat.cols;j++)
        {
                tmp[i][j]=mat.at<float>(i,j);
                if (tmp[i][j]>max) max=tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<mat.cols;i++) for (int j=0;j<mat.rows;j++) tmp[j][i]/=max;
    k_means(tmp,mat.rows,128,K_CLUSTER,KMEANSDIS,kcent);
    for (int i=0;i<K_CLUSTER;i++) for (int j=0;j<128;j++) kcent[i][j]*=max;
    for (int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++)free(tmp[i]);
    free(tmp);
}
```

The fault ocurred in this line,

```
for (int i=0;i<mat.rows;i++)free(tmp[i]);
```

and the function k_means() doesn't change the first parameter. Who can help me?

P.S. 
Here is the definition of k_means()

```
int k_means(double **data, int n, int m, int k, double t, double **centroids)
```

and here is the _double** kcent_

```
kcent=(double**)calloc(K_CLUSTER,sizeof(double*));
for (int i=0;i<K_CLUSTER;i++) kcent[i]=(double*)calloc(128,sizeof(double));
```

I think this part is correctly.

Comment: are you calling the function correctly? everything else looks fine

Comment: does `k_means` change `mat.rows` at all? I compiled this without the `k_` functions and it worked fine with valgrind

Comment: You left out the definition of `kcent`, perhaps you're going outside of its bounds? The problem is probably memory corruption of the pointers before you get to the `free`.

Comment: Have you left out some code, or is `f[]` really not used?

Comment: Set the debugger's memory window to show the memory past the end of the row that gets corrupted. The step through the code - you'll be able to easily see when the memory gets changed and will be able to zero in on the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems to be very clear that that it is heap corruption.

Try to move the free() for loop, above the function call k_means() and comment out the rest of your program.

I am suspicious that this is what corrupting the Heap!

If this experiment frees the memory correctly, You know the bug is in k_means() function...

Comment: Yeah...finally I found the bug is in k_means() and know I correct it...thank you...

Answer (score -1):

you dont use pointer address you got from calloc in free, therefore memory start address pointed by free() argument differs. If i am not wrong you can't get whole bunch of memory then free them in parts , if this is what are you trying to achieve. At least with malloc.

In free() use same value what you got from calloc().